# How to properly edit a TXT file created in Windows using VI editor

Tags: windows, vi, text, newlines

I created a [text file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yp40qsjwecpf5kg/prova2.txt?dl=0) (link goes to DropBox) with a Windows application and now I MUST edit it with VI in Unix.

Once I opened the file, I realized that I cannot easily navigate within the lines in VI. If I use the up and down arrow, I skip a whole big line in the document, which does not correspond to the line I see in VI. This does not make it easy for me to edit the file.

Is there a way to convert the file to UNIX format, in which I can easily navigate through the lines using VI? I tried to use the command Perl or dos2unix, but they did not work.

Comment: There are five lines in that file (three long lines of text and a couple of blanks). What's the problem?

Answer (score 5):

The file is already in Unix format.  Your problem is that you do not know what a line is.

Each of your paragraphs is a *single long line of text*.  Navigation in Joy `vi` (and in Bostic `nvi`) proceeds by lines, and long lines wrap onto *multiple rows on the screen*.   So the up and down motions move up and down several screen rows, but only actually move to the *next/previous line in the document*.

VIM and NeoVIM, and various other `vi` clones, offer the ability to turn line-wrap off, with `:set nowrap`.  In this case, long lines are only partly displayed, with sideways scrolling, and one line is a single screen row.  So the up and down motions move just one screen row, because that's the same as a document line.

They also offer alternative motions.  <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> moves up one screen row, for example, as opposed to <kbd>k</kbd> moving up one document line.

## Further reading

- Sven Guckes (2017-08-07). *[Vi Clones and HomePages](http://www.guckes.net/vi/clones.php3)*.  guckes.net.
- [`:help wrap-off`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/intro.html#wrap-off)
- [`:help gk`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/motion.html#gk)

Comment: Wrapped lines do look confusing. I often tell vi to :set nu which adds a line number in a different colour, and breaks up the wrap very visibly. The line numbers are protected.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and for the clarification. The issue is that have to send the document to a person who prefers to use the classic VI for editing. From what you've said, I've got that there is no way to navigate within a single line in VI. g k in VI have the same function as the up and down arrows ...